# Is there a limit to how many power moons you can buy at Crazy Cap stores?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

After beating the game, you have the option to buy more power moons from the Crazy Cap store for 100 coins. I bought 15 of them at Mushroom Kingdom... but it doesn't seem to stop. And it doesn't seem like this count carries over to other shop locations.

Is there a limit to how many power moons I could buy?

Comment: There's no limit to how many you can buy, but your "total moons" count (as appearing on the sail of the Odyssey) is capped at 999.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no limit. You can do this at any store that sells these as well, giving you more power moons than you would ordinarily find in game. I suspect this exists to offset the harder-to-find power moons, giving you the ability to keep exploring post-game content without having to find every power moon.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too as I'm trying to clear the rest of the worlds. Certain costume pieces are gated based on how many power moons you have. I'm finding that getting a lot of them are pretty difficult, even for me. I'd imagine some players would not like that too much.

Comment: @JeffMercado Agreed. I'm not a casual player, but I certainly get stuck trying to find some of these blasted power moons. Being able to buy them helps a ton.

Comment: or they moon in the wooded kingdom where you have to hit a sheep through a course, I can't seem to beat that thing

Comment: Sad that I spent 2200 gold coins on these power moons. I was half way to the skeleton costume. I figured there was a finite number I could buy, but when I saw it was still letting me buy 10 more (would have brought me to 32 bought) I figured I should check if there was actually a maximum number I could buy.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: I stopped at 13 initially, after getting one the first time around, then one more, then 10, then another one. In the end, my OCD tendencies made me get 15 from every single store even if I didn't need it. Would have preferred 10 but being at 13, and not a multiple of 5, I couldn't leave it at that. Ultimately I would prefer 50 or 100 but, that's a little too much, even for me.